# Python Async requests with proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, pythonanywhere

Is there a way to have async requests in python using an http proxy, which has been set by the PAAS provider (pythonanywhere) on the requests module but not aiohttp which uses the websocket API ?

Thanks.

Comment: The [aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html?highlight=proxy#proxy-support) cover how to set up a proxy and the details you need are [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/)

Comment: You are 100% right, thanks. It seems simple but I'm new to python and missed it. I can mark it as an answer if you want.